# Android rename vs rename file

Tags: android, android-studio

What is difference if i go in android studio:

- refactor -> rename file
- refactor -> rename

Is it maybe that "rename file" renames only file and "rename" renames file and all other occurrences of that name in project..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rename will rename the class and the file names, rename file will only rename the file name but not the class name.
Most of the times you should use the 'rename' option to make sure rename the class and all it usages.